# Implementing Nhibernate one to many mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class School and another class Teachers. now every school can contain m Teachers and one Teacher may be part of more than one school. But in the Teachers class I dont want a property that tells me which Schools a teacher is part of.

Thus,

```
public class School
{
public virtual int Id {get;set;}
public virtual string Name {get;set;}
public virtual IList<Teacher> Teachers {get;set;}
    public School()
    {
    Teachers=new List();
    }
}
```

And the mapping for the same is

```
public class SchoolMap:ClassMap<School>
{
    public SchoolMap()
    {
    Id(x=>x.Id);
    Map(x=>x.Name);
    HasMany(x=>x.Teachers);
    }
}
```

and Teacher is defined as

```
public class Teacher
{
public virtual int Id {get;set;}
public virtual int Name {get;set;}
}
```

and the expected simple mapping is defined.

Now I wish to join these tables right so that when I create a School object and then add Teachers to it and save it I want it to be stored in a mapping table the columns of which should be the following SchoolId,TeacherId.

Now how do i use this table in my mapping so that when I save the School object my teachers are also stored in the db and on retrieving the School object I retrieve the Teachers too.

Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **[this](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started)**:

`HasMany(x => x.Teachers).Inverse().Cascade.All();`